# Pipe cleaning machine without guide hose - how to prevent tile and furniture damage?

Tags: pipe, drainage, clog

Looking for a pipe cleaning machine, I see only the very expensive ones with a guide hose ("Spiralschutzschlauch") that will protect the bathroom from fast-rotating spiral ends (2.5 - 5 m!). In contrast, the medium-priced ones do not seem to have such a guide hose.
Needless to say, that for occasional home use, I cannot spent >> $ 1000, just to get a simple plastic hose with attachment to the machine.

**Question:** How would one prevent vast damage of tiles and furniture without sucha guide hose, when the spring is spinning quite fast? Has someone attached a kind of self-made guide hose?

Example **with** guide hose: >> $ 1000
Edit: I removed the brandname and link and blacked out the (hardly readable) name on the device.
[image]

Example **without** guide hose: ~ $ 200
(at least a guide hose is never depicted or mentioned in a variety of similar machines in this price range from different manufacturers and on different online stores - in case someone obtained such a machine around $200 *with* guide hose, please let me know - yes/no, acc. to guidelines no brandname needed)
[image: Arebos Pipe cleaning device]

**Edit:** as requested, I removed the brand names. I am not looking for shopping recommendations (or even want to advertise) - I simply want to know how to deal with such a type of mashine without causing damage, therefore I put the (unaltered) question in bold face and addedthe 2nd part of the title. Since there are lots of them sold from a variety of brands, I guess there is some trick.
I am also happy for "alternative" answers that demonstrate that a different approach is equally or more effective but cheaper, if based on evidence and not personal opinion only.

Comment: Personally, I think a hand-powered augur where the spring is coiled up in the handle and you can simply stop winding if anything gets out of hand is more appropriate for home use, if having an augur at all for home use. I inherited one, and have yet to find a use for it after several decades. If I felt the need for a larger or powered augur without an associated plumber, I'd go to the tool rental shop.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: I was intrigued by the variety of tools (drillbits etc., depicted at the lower part of the 2nd image) that are available usually only for the bigger motor-powered ones, not for hand-held ones (except for hand-held ROSPIMATIC, which is even more expensive than the cheaper one above). I have made mediocre experiencewith the simple hand-held devices, and clogged pipes are a recurrent problem in my home and the homes of my relatives and friends.

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here ... please edit your post ... remove the references to manufacturers and online stores

Comment: Unless you are going into business, manual or rental units probably cheaper.  Do you really need the fancy stuff or it just seems nice to have?

Comment: @jsotola: I edited the Q to make clear I am not looking for shopping but practical advice.